# Jump iteration inside Object.each()

Tags: mootools

Is there a way to jump the current iteration inside `Object.each()` if a condition is met?

I could use:

```
Object.each(myObject, function(item, key){
    if(key != 'someString'){
        //do everything
    }
});
```

but i would like something like

```
Object.each(myObject, function(item, key){
    if(key == 'someString') continue;
});
```

Comment: heh, like `Array.some` for Objects? I know it's radical but have you considered using a normal `for(key in myObject){}` loop? it's still javascript :)

Comment: see answer. Object.some / Object.every. with same behaviour as in Array. it's not even available in lodash/underscore, this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the same stuff for objects as we have for Arrays.

P.S. I hope btw your question is about `break`, right? not `continue`?

Because to `continue` all you need to do is return early from the callback fn of your Object.each...

```
Object.each(myObject, function(item, key){
    if(key == 'someString') return;
    // code here will run only if key is somethingelse.
});
```

Anyway, implementing Object.every and Object.some (not on the proto, just hosted on Object)

```
(function(){
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.hasOwnProperty;
    Object.extend({
        some: function(obj, cb, bind){
            for (var k in obj){
                if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)){
                    if (cb.call(bind, obj[k], k, obj)) break;
                }
            }
        },
        every: function(obj, cb, bind){
            for (var k in obj){
                if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)){
                    if (!cb.call(bind, obj[k], k, obj)) break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

Here is some use:

```
var foo = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    bar: 'haha',
    three: 3
};

// loop keys until the key is bar then stop.
Object.some(foo, function(value, key){
    console.log(key, value);
    return key === 'bar';
});

// loop keys until a non-number is encountered, then stop
Object.every(foo, function(value, key){
    console.log(key, value);
    return typeof value === 'number';
});
```

Comment: Well, my question was about `continue` and my ignorance kept me away from trying `return`, so thanks for solution! Handy idea to extend Object to have `some` & `every`. Was going for your comment/suggestion to go back to basics and use a *good old for loop*: http://jsfiddle.net/jvt28/, that works good also. Thank you!